# Showing multiple image with php failed to rotate with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas

i want to show image with php and rotate that image using canvas+jquery. the problem is when single image all works well. but when imgae show more than one, rotate failed. i know the problem is image id or the canvas id on javascript, but i can't solve this. can you help me?

here is my php code :

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($aksi)):?>

    <div>
        <img src="image/<?php echo $data['dir']; ?>" alt="" id="image" />
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <p>
        <strong>Rotate Image: </strong>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="resetImage">Reset Image</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="rotate90">90&deg;</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="rotate180">180&deg;</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="rotate270">270&deg;</a>
    </p>


    <?php 
$no++;
endwhile;
?>
```

and here is javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">



var img = null, canvas = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
   //  Initialize image and canvas
   img = document.getElementById('image');
   canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

   if(!canvas || !canvas.getContext){
       canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
   } else {
       img.style.position = 'absolute';
       img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
   rotateImage(0);

   //  Handle clicks for control links
   $('#resetImage').click(function(){ rotateImage(0); });
   $('#rotate90').click(function(){ rotateImage(90); });
   $('#rotate180').click(function(){ rotateImage(180); });
   $('#rotate270').click(function(){ rotateImage(270); });
});

function rotateImage(degree)
{
    if(document.getElementById('canvas')){
       var cContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var cw = img.width, ch = img.height, cx = 0, cy = 0;

       //   Calculate new canvas size and x/y coorditates for image
       switch(degree){
            case 90:
                cw = img.height;
                ch = img.width;
                cy = img.height * (-1);
                break;
            case 180:
                cx = img.width * (-1);
                cy = img.height * (-1);
                break;
            case 270:
                cw = img.height;
                ch = img.width;
                cx = img.width * (-1);
                break;
       }

        //  Rotate image            
        canvas.setAttribute('width', cw);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', ch);
        cContext.rotate(degree * Math.PI / 180);
        cContext.drawImage(img, cx, cy);
    } else {
        //  Use DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage filter for MSIE
        switch(degree){
            case 0: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)'; break;
            case 90: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)'; break;
            case 180: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)'; break;
            case 270: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)'; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have more than 1 element on the page with any given ID. Because you have done this, your code is broken. How do you expect **(a)** jQuery to know which one of the `#rotate` buttons should have the event handler attached and then **(b)** for the code that handles the button to have any idea which image it should apply the transform to? _EDIT_: same goes for the canvas.

Comment: okay. then what should i do sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing...
Do not use the ID tag for items that repeat several times. Change it for the Class tag and call me after ;)

My best!

Comment: In your php file, change the ID tag to Class tag for the swap images.
<img src="image/<?php echo $data['dir']; ?>" alt="" class="image" />

For your JS:
img = document. getElementsByClassName('image');

Check your CSS file too.